# Sample spaces for these 3 related marble drawing experiments, and counting their probabilities (I've done them - please check my answer?)

Tags: probability, probability-theory, solution-verification, independence

Say we have a box with 5 red marbles and 6 green marbles. We consider the following three related experiments, their sample spaces and corresponding probabilities of the events involved:

i) **$E:=$Drawing with replacement 3 marbles from the box:**
I'm confused here: I'm having the following answers and not sure which one is correct:

Let the set $S=\{R,R,R,R,R,G,G,G,G,G,G\}$ denote the set of all marbles.
Then $\Omega=S \times S \times S, n(\Omega) = 11^3.$ Therefore $P(E)= 1/11^3.$ **Is this correct?**

ii) **Drawing 3 marbles simultaneously from the box:**

Is $\Omega$ just set of all choices of 3 marble at a time, so $n(\Omega)= {11\choose 3}$ and so the probability of choosing three marbles simultaneously is: $\frac{1}{11 \choose 3}?$ **Is this correct?**

iii) **Drawing successively 3 marbles from the box:**

I think in this case it's without replacement, so we're not putting the marbles back into the box. back again. So in this case $n(\Omega)= 11 \times 10 \times 9, P(E) = 1/n(\Omega),$ **is this correct?**

Comment: The sizes of your sample spaces are correct.  Your values for $P(E)$ seem to be the probability of selecting three particular marbles from the box.  Unless the red and green marbles are labeled, it would be hard to distinguish a particular set of, say, two green marbles and one red marble from another set of two green marbles and one red marble.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Thank you - that's an important point for sure! So how would I modify the probabilities accordingly, in each of these three cases?

Comment: @N.F.Taussig In my answers, I didn't use the color of the marbles though, I always used 11 and not 5 or 6 in my answers, so I'm not sure which of the three answers need to be modified and how?

Comment: The answer will depend on the particular event you are considering.  For instance, if the event is selecting two green marbles and one red marble, there are $6 \cdot 6 \cdot 5 \cdot 3$ ways to do that in the first scenario since there are six ways to select each green marble, five ways to select a red marble, and three positions in which the red marble could appear.  In the second scenario, there are $\binom{6}{2}\binom{5}{1}$ ways to select two of the six green marbles and one of the five red marbles.  In the third scenario, there are $3 \cdot 6 \cdot 5 \cdot 5$ such selections.